# GitHub Actions upload docker compose 3 services to nexus

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, nexus, sonatype

i have a react-js application with the following services, created by docker-compose: backend (java), frontend (react js), db (mariadb). i have build a pipeline by GitHub Actions and everything is working, i want to upload everything to nexus repository, how can i do that?

this is my workflow yaml:

```
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "dev" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "dev" ]

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build the compose
      run: docker compose build

  test:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: up the compose
      run: docker compose up -d
```

this is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: example
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db-password
    image: mariadb:10.6.4-focal
    restart: always
    secrets:
      - db-password
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - spring-mysql
  backend:
    build:
      context: backend/Dockerfile
      target: development
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: db
    networks:
      - react-spring
      - spring-mysql
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure:5
  frontend:
    build:
      context: frontend/Dockerfile
      target: development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - react-spring
    depends_on:
      - backend
volumes:
  db-data: {}
secrets:
  db-password:
    file: db/password.txt
networks:
  react-spring: {}
  spring-mysql: {}
```